# Resizing page cuts off linear gradient

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, linear-gradients

Whenever I resize the page, the linear gradient gets cut off.

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cfdfff, #75b5e3);
    margin: 0; 
}
```

When the page is resized, the body no longer takes up 100% of the page, and therefore the gradient is cut off. (White space is rest of page)
If I use a static color as the background, this issue does not happen.

[image: cut off gradient]

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `min-height` instead of `height`

```css
html {
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cfdfff, #75b5e3);
    margin: 0;
} 

div{
  width: 200px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```